# Does Replace() remove child table rows?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I'm using the `replace` [operation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.instances.databases.sessions/commit#Mutation), because -- if a row already exists -- I want non-specified values to be set to NULL.  If the table whose rows I am replacing has child tables, will corresponding child table rows be deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

You can think of a `replace` as a `delete` of the specified rows -- plus all nested child table rows -- followed by an `insert` of a new row.